# How can I ask questions on this site anonymously?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've just joined this site and would like to ask a question, but I'm concerned about employers/colleagues etc seeing my posts.

How do I keep the questions anonymous?

Comment: Ask without logging in...?

Comment: You can perhaps find some solutions in answers to [Can you add an ask anonymously feature for Stack Exchange sites like this and onstartups?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/395/can-you-add-an-ask-anonymously-feature-for-stack-exchange-sites-like-this-and-on)

Comment: @kevin No longer possible. Anonymous posting is now disabled on this site because [trolls make it so we can't have nice things](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/is-creating-anonymous-questions-disabled-on-purpose/6715#6715).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple option: make an account that doesn't have your real name or picture. Don't fill out your profile with identifying information.  (Who am I anyway?)

There are some downsides to this, for instance, if you want to use the careers site, or want to brag about your points in an interview.

Comment: I disagree with this. Why make a separate account rather than just not using an account atall?, as suggested by Oded

Comment: The general consensus is that Oded's way is a better one, and I don't disagree.

Comment: Isn't this technically against stack exchange rules?

Answer (score 16):

Simple.

Open an anonymous browser session (InPrivate, incognito, whatever it is called in the browser you are on).

We don't require people to be logged in for them to ask a question (or answer, for that matter).

Comment: @JimG.: Huh? It sure looks to me like there's an account attached to that question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @GreenMatt: I don't think that somebody would want to create their "permanent" alias as `Made A Bad Mistake`. ;) That's why I concluded that it must be a throwaway account. // But you're right (and I was wrong) - It's not the same as Oded suggested.

Comment: @JimG.: Agreed about that being a throwaway account, which is what thursdaysgeek was suggesting, not Oded.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case at this point in time.

Comment: @Rotem - it is something that can be done site-by-site and ends up depending on the moderators and community managers in regards to when to stop anonymous posting. I've no idea which sites do and do not allow it these days, as the days I've worked for SO are long past.

Comment: As of May 2020 [anonymous posting has been disabled on this site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6713/25739). This may be reversed in future at which point this answer would again apply.

Comment: How can you accept an answer or post a comment to make your question clearer once your session is gone?