# Is creating anonymous questions disabled on purpose?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, asking-questions, new-users

I cannot create anonymous questions anymore on The Workplace, is this intended behavior?

I tried to create an incognito session in Chrome and post a question, which redirects me to the login/signup screen.

Comment: It's worth noting that this site is the sole main Q&A site to require registration to both ask *and answer* questions.

Answer (score 11):

> Is creating anonymous questions disabled on purpose?

**Yes.** Posting by unregistered accounts was disabled some time in April as part of our and the Community Team's efforts to combat a recent surge in spam and troll questions.

To confirm, both asking and answerings questions now requires registration:

> You must be logged in to ask a question on The Workplace
>
> You must log in to answer this question.

Comment: please consider tagging this [meta-tag:status-bydesign] to help readers see that this became an official site feature. Also I wonder if registration is required to answer questions or only for asking (you probably better [edit] this answer to clarify this)

Answer (score 5):

I guess it is; there are one or more rather persistent trolls on this site, and while having to register doesn't stop them entirely, it makes it a bit more difficult for them. The Workplace is not alone in this regard; on some other sites like Stack Overflow you need to register as well to post a question, though question quality is there the main reason for this.

Comment: Thats really unfortunate, i rather not create a delicate question on my main account.

Comment: I understand, but then it's fine to use another email address (even a throwaway one which can't be traced back to you) to register an account just for this purpose. Just be sure not to interact with it on your main account (that includes voting).